# Reverse solve chi-squre statistic to find number of observations

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size

I am trying to prove that two proportions are equal with 95% confidence. I have a total population Tp (10000), and wins in that population of Wp (2000). My sample size is Ts (1500). I need to solve for Ws, the number of wins that have to be observed in the sample to prove the sample is proportional to the population.

I've got that I need a test stat of 3.842 (qchisq(0.95, df = 1)). I'm having trouble reversing the Pearson test to come up with Wp. Since I can't calculate the expected value with a missing number, I'm a little stuck.

Comment: (1) You use "Wp" for two different quantities--could you fix that? (2) Why are you sampling when you know all about the population? (3) What does it mean that the "sample is proportional to the population"?  (4) Regardless of (3), it's unlikely you can statistically "prove" any such statement, so some clarification about what you really want to demonstrate would help.

Comment: Variable names have been corrected, thanks. For each win, there are a number of reports and other work that has to be done, so that's the reason for a sample. The goal is to prove that sample win frequency is the same as the population win frequency.

Comment: You cannot "prove that sample win frequency is the same as the population win frequency."

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be thinking that a failure to reject in a chi-squared test shows the two proportions are the same, but it doesn't (failure to show an effect doesn't mean the effect is absent, since you can have a small effect for which the sample size wasn't big enough to reliably pick up whatever effect you had)

You can't show that the two proportions are the same (the nearest you'd get to that would be an equivalence test, if you can specify an equivalence criterion in your situation).

I think your actual question is "what values of the number of wins in the sample (X) would not lead to rejection with a chi-squared test at the 5% level?"

If that's the case, we have the following table:

```
            Sampled   Not sampled   Total

Wins          X        2000-X        2000
Not-Wins   1500-X      6500+X        8000

Total       1500        8500        10000
```

The chi-squared statistic for an observed $X$ of $x$ is $(x-300)^2\cdot (\frac{_1}{^{300}}+\frac{_1}{^{1200}}+\frac{_1}{^{1700}}+\frac{_1}{^{6800}})$ (without continuity correction) so we want to see where that's less than $3.84146$. We can easily solve this algebraically - the quadratic formula gives the bounds as $300\pm\sqrt{\Delta}$ where $\Delta=\frac{_{3.84146}}{^{\frac{_1}{^{300}}+\frac{_1}{^{1200}}+\frac{_1}{^{1700}}+\frac{_1}{^{6800}}}}$ - but since you seem to be familiar with R, let's just use it to solve our problem:

```
f <- function(x) (x-300)^2*(1/300+1/1200+1/1700+1/6800)
x <- 250:350
range(x[f(x)<qchisq(.95,1)])
[1] 273 327
```

Alternatively

```
f <- function(x) {chisq.test(matrix(c(x,2000-x,1500-x,6500+x),nr=2),
               correct=FALSE)$p.value}
range(x[sapply(x,f)>.05])
```

gives the same result.

So the largest and smallest $x$'s that would not lead to rejection are 273 and 327.

(If you apply Yates' correction - simply by removing "`correct=FALSE`" above, which is the default in R - then it changes to 272 and 328)

[image: Plot of chi-squared test statistics vs x, both uncorrected and corrected, with critical threshold 3.84146 marked in]